# × TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

I am a beginner learning react and redux. I wrote this demo about how to use connect.js in redux. Searching this kind of question but there is no right answer for my code. I got a undefined context. Is it typo? or I passed context in a wrong way? Thanks in advance. Here is my code.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import store from "./store";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

/store/index.js

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducer from "./reducer.js";
const store = createStore(reducer);
export default store;
```

/store/reducer.js

```
import { ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV } from './constants.js'

// or initialState
const defaultState = {
  counter: 0
}

function reducer(state = defaultState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD:
      return {...state, counter: state.counter + action.num};
    case SUB:
      return {...state, counter: state.counter - action.num};
    case MUL:
      return {...state, counter: state.counter * action.num};
    case DIV:
      return {...state, counter: state.counter / action.num};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer
```

connect.js

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { StoreContext } from "./context";

export default function connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) {
  return function enhanceHOC(WrappedCpn) {
    class EnhanceCpn extends PureComponent {
      constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        console.log('connect props', props);
        console.log('connect context', context);  // context is undefined here
        this.state = {
          storeState: mapStateToProps(context.getState()),
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.unSubscribe = this.context.subscribe(() => {
          this.setState({
            counter: mapStateToProps(this.context.getState()),
          });
        });
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        this.unSubscribe();
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <WrappedCpn
            {...this.props}
            {...mapStateToProps(this.context.getState())}
            {...mapDispatchToProps(this.context.dispatch)}
          />
        );
      }
    }
    EnhanceCpn.contextType = StoreContext;
    return EnhanceCpn;
  };
}
```

context.js

```
import React from "react";
const StoreContext = React.createContext();
export {
  StoreContext
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import My from './pages/my'

export default class App extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    console.log('APP props', props);
    console.log('APP context', context); // context got value
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <My />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

my.js

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { sub, mul } from '../store/actionCreators'
import connect from '../utils/connect'

class My extends PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h3>my</h3>
      <h3>counter: { this.props.counter }</h3>
      <button onClick={e => this.props.subNum()}>-2</button>
      <button onClick={e => this.props.mulNUm(5)}>*5</button>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  counter: state.counter
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  subNum: (num = -2) => {
    dispatch(sub(num))
  },
  mulNUm: num => {
    dispatch(mul(num))
  }

})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(My)
```

actionCreators.js

```
import { ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV } from './constants.js'

export function add(num) {
  return {
    type: ADD,
    num
  }
}

export const sub = (num) => {
  return {
    type: SUB,
    num
  }
}

export const mul = (num) => ({
  type: MUL,
  num
})

export const div = num => ({
  type: DIV,
  num
})
```

constants.js

```
const ADD = 'ADD_ACTION'
const SUB = 'SUB_ACTION'
const MUL = 'MUL_ACTION'
const DIV = 'DIV_ACTION'

export { ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV }
```

Comment: Where is your `actionCreators`?

Comment: Are you trying to create your own `connect` HOC for fun or something? Why not use/leverage `react-redux`? If I'm not mistaken React deprecated the `constructor(props, context)` signature.

Comment: I edit my question and post  actionCreators.js. yes, I am trying to create my own connect hoc. constructor(props, context) in App.js is working

Comment: If you are learning redux, you might as well learn the [modern style](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) for writing reducers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype), here is what it says with regards to `Class.contextType`:

> The `contextType` property on a class can be assigned a Context object
> created by [`React.createContext()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext). Using this property lets you
> consume the nearest current value of that Context type using
> `this.context`. You can reference this in any of the lifecycle methods
> including the render function.

It seems that in your case, you are just missing passing your custom `StoreContext` to redux `Provider` with the `context` props

You need to do something like:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import store from "./store";
import { StoreContext } from "./context";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store} context={StoreContext}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

See also https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#providing-custom-context

Comment: Thanks for the answer. <StoreContext.Provider value={store}> works for me

Comment: @GrahamQuan You should consider marking this the accepted answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Can you please create a sandbox for this?

Answer (score 4):

i got same issues
i just have to change were i have my configure store from this

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import basketReducer from "../slices/basketSlice";
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    basket: basketReducer,
       },
         });
```

to this

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import basketReducer from "../slices/basketSlice";
export default configureStore({
 reducer: {
  basket: basketReducer,
    },
     });
```

and this method works for me
i also find out when i play around with the code to understand why it happen and see if i broke it what will happen this is my finding and observation from it

note concerning redux
if you used the below as import in your _app.js

```
import { store } from "../stores/store";
```

then
the global store should be rewritten like this

```
 export const store = configureStore({
      reducer: {
        basket: basketReducer,
      },
    });
```

but if you import it like this with out distructuring it[store] or without the curly bracket

```
import store  from "../stores/store";
```

then
you should write the store like this

```
 export default configureStore({
                reducer: {
                  basket: basketReducer,
                },
              });
```

Both ways works for me

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue and solved by creating store on the same file as the root component where Provider is applied. Example code below:

```
 <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
    <App />
 </Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState')

Solution:

(1) make a file `store.js` in your redux folder and you can copy the code

```js
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
    import logger from 'redux-logger';
    
    import rootReducer from "./root-reducer";
    
    const middlewares = [logger];
    
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
    
    export default store;
```

(2) then just import the file in index.js file

```xml
     <Provider store={store}>
          <BrowserRouter>
             <App />
          </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
```